# How to passing props and use it with named slot in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

I am having problems with use slot props on a named slot in Svelte.

Svelte document mentioned: `Named slots can also have props; use the let directive on an element with a slot="..." attribute, instead of on the component itself.`  but I don't know how to use it.

Docs: https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/slot-props

I have code example like this.

```html
// $lib/components/Navbar.svelte
import Lead from './Lead.svelte'
import Trail from './Trail.svelte'
<nav>
  <slot name="lead" {Lead}>(lead)</slot>
  <ul>
    <slot name="trail" {Item}>(trail)</slot>
  </ul>
</nav>

// using
import Navbar from '$lib/components/Navbar.svelte'

// error: Property 'default' does not exist on type '{ lead: { Lead: typeof Lead__SvelteComponent }; };

<Navbar let:{Lead}> // <= error at this line
  <svelte:fragment slot="lead">
    <Lead {my_props}>
      <span>More</span>
    </Lead>
  </svelte:fragment>
</Navbar>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs say, the `let:` should be on the element with the `slot="..."`. Also, the syntax is either just `let:prop` or `let:prop={renamedProp}` if you want to change the name that refers to the property from the slot.

```html
<svelte:fragment slot="lead" let:Lead >...
```

Comment: Oh, really simple and clear. Thank you so much @brunnerh